# Handling Ambiguous Column Names

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im in a position where I cannot alter the table structure of my database and I have Ambiguous Column Names in [table1] and [table2]. I do not need to use any fields from [table2] but its existence is necessary to relate to another table. Is there a way that I handle this?

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you tried, and the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you refer to one of the ambiguous column names you should specify the table name or alias.

```
SELECT ...
FROM [table1]
JOIN [table2]
ON [table1].ambiguous_column = [table2].ambiguous_column
AND ...
```

Answer (score 3):

use table aliases

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY A.FIELD
```

Answer (score 1):

use the SQL statement **AS** to create uniquel names

```
SELECT 
  A.feld1  AS F1,
  A.feld2  AS F2,
  B.feld1  AS F3
FROM table1 AS A
JOIN table2 AS B ON A.id = B.id
ORDER BY A.field1
```